# What is the logic behind lexographic string comparation in java?

Tags: java

I am implementing a simple comparator to order object in a TreeSet by names (alpabetically) in java. The result is diferent from what I was expecting and I have a hard time understanding the logic behind java's String compareTo() method. My expectation is that the string would be ordered alphabetically.

Here is the code listing:

**Student Class**

```
enum Grade{ A, B, C; }

class Student {

    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private int rollNumber;
    private double totalMarks;
    private Grade grade;

    public Student(int studentId, String studentName)
    {
        this.studentId=this.rollNumber=studentId;
        this.studentName=studentName;
    }

    public Student(String studentName, int rollNumber)
    {
        this.studentId=this.rollNumber=rollNumber;
        this.studentName=studentName;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rollNumber
     */
    public int getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param rollNumber the rollNumber to set
     */
    public void setRollNumber(int rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }    

    /**
     * @return the totalMarks
     */
    public double getTotalMarks() {
        return totalMarks;
    }

    /**
     * @param totalMarks the totalMarks to set
     */
    public void setTotalMarks(double totalMarks) {
        this.totalMarks = totalMarks;
        calculateGrade();
    }

    public void calculateGrade() {

        if(this.totalMarks >= 60) this.grade = Grade.A;

        else if(this.totalMarks > 40 && this.totalMarks < 60) this.grade = Grade.B;

        else this.grade = Grade.C;

    }

    private Grade getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{name: %s, rollNumber: %d, totalMarks: %f, Grade: %s}", 
                studentName, 
                this.rollNumber,
                this.totalMarks,
                this.getGrade());
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if(obj instanceof Student) {
            Student student = (Student) obj;
            return student.rollNumber == this.rollNumber;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.rollNumber;
    }
}
```

**Student Comparator Class**

```
class StudentNameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getStudentName().compareTo(o2.toString())*-1; //reverse ordering
    }

}
```

**Test Comparator**

```
public class TestComparator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creating a new Set object of type Student
        Set<Student> nameComparatorStudentTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(new StudentNameComparator());

        Student student1 = new Student("Adam",101);
        student1.setTotalMarks(Math.random()*100);
        Student student2 = new Student("Jane",102);
        student2.setTotalMarks(Math.random()*100);
        Student student3 = new Student("Ngozi",103);
        student3.setTotalMarks(Math.random()*100);
        Student student4 = new Student("James",104);
        student4.setTotalMarks(Math.random()*100);
        Student student5 = new Student("Linda",105);
        student5.setTotalMarks(Math.random()*100);

        nameComparatorStudentTreeSet.add(student1);
        nameComparatorStudentTreeSet.add(student3);
        nameComparatorStudentTreeSet.add(student2);
        nameComparatorStudentTreeSet.add(student4);        
        nameComparatorStudentTreeSet.add(student5);

        System.out.println(nameComparatorStudentTreeSet);

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[
  {name: Adam, rollNumber: 101, totalMarks: 60.376270, Grade: A}, 
  {name: Jane, rollNumber: 102, totalMarks: 91.489294, Grade: A}, 
  {name: Ngozi, rollNumber: 103, totalMarks: 91.367159, Grade: A}, 
  {name: James, rollNumber: 104, totalMarks: 47.827461, Grade: B}, 
  {name: Linda, rollNumber: 105, totalMarks: 65.531522, Grade: A}
]
```

Java fiddle: [jdoodle.com/a/1rm7](http://jdoodle.com/a/1rm7)

Comment: I think you mean `o2.getStudentName().toString()`.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Shmosel, I got a comparing the getName() method on o1 and o2, corrected the sorting. The comparator class should be:

```
class StudentNameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getStudentName().compareTo(o2.getStudentName())*-1; //reverse ordering
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues here to sort out:

- Your comparison operator is incorrect - it's not comparing names
- Your comparator must be consistent with equals to implement the set operation (see documentation for `TreeSet` for details)

I would recommend you use the `Comparator` static methods to construct your comparison rather than implement your own `compareTo`. It's safer and clearer:

```
Comparator<Student> nameOrder = Comparator.comparing(Student::getStudentName);

Set<Student> students = new TreeSet<>(nameOrder.reverse());
```

Comment: As you rightly pointed out, the comparison operation is incorrect. I was able to sort alphabetically by making shmosel's correction.

Comment: This works as expected, however, the exercise I am working on requires the implementation of a Custom comparator that extends the Comparator interface.